# Is it possible to attach jQuery to a loaded page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to attach jQuery to a web page which is completely loaded. For example, I want to attach jQuery to this current page *(stackoverflow)* and then use it.

Well I did it:

[image]

But I don't see any reaction of the code I've written. I mean that `alert` won't be shown when I click on the document.

Anyway, is it possible to I attach a library like jQuery to a loaded page and writing some JS codes in it?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. How are you attaching jQuery to an existing page? Are you just using your browser DOM inspector to modify the contents of an existing page or you are looking for some programmatic way?

Comment: Using console only, you can't just add new nodes to DOM, that won't work. Script must load when page load.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Currently I've used `inspect` of chrome browser for attaching. Also, is there any programmatic approach for doing that??

Comment: If you own the website then of course that there's a programmatic way. If you don't, then please don't expect to be able to achieve anything like that - if this was possible then the internet wouldn't have existed the way we know it today :-)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov ha ha ha .. no I'm not the owner of the website I want to parse it. Anyway, is there any working way to I attach jQuery to a loaded page?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Alright, attaching jQuery aside. Is there any approach to make me able to write a working JS function on the dom which is loaded?

Comment: Where do you want to write this function if you do not own the website? Are you trying to do this only using the developer toolbar of your Chrome browser? I am still very confused about what you are asking and trying to achieve.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov On the `Inspect` tool of the browser. Look, I've tested adding an event on a input, something like this: `onfocus="(function(e){e.value='Sajad'; e.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));})(this)"`. If you add this code as an input attribute, it will work when you focus on that input. Now I want to write a separate function *(not writing codes as inline)*, is it possible?

Comment: Of course that it's possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to add some onclick handler to the document using your browser, then simply open the console and type the following:

```
document.onclick = function() { alert("document clicked"); };
```

Then go clicking around:

[image]

Comment: great .. that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: Just do you know why it doesn't work when I write it as a *separated* function? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XymrW.png

Comment: Because you should write `document.onclick = test;` instead of `document.onclick = test();`. In the first case you are assigning the onclick handler to your `test` function reference whereas in the second you are assigning it to the result of the `test()` function call which of course is `void`. You cannot possibly expect the second to be of any usefulness.

Comment: You're right ...! anyway thanks alot, I guess I will need to ask 2 or even 4 more questions later *(tomorrow, at work)*. You seem good in such cases `:-)`

Comment: Oh I forgot to ask this: attaching jQuery is impossible in the same way *(using browser's console)*. right?

Comment: Of course that it is possible with jQuery as well, just inject a dynamic script tag inside your DOM to load jQuery and then use it: `var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
script.onload = function () {
    $(document).on("click", function() {
        alert("document clicked");
    });
};
document.body.appendChild(script);`